# Enabling Shell colours through Putty SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, .bash-profile

I have set a number of configurations in my .bashrc file to set the appearance of shell on my Redhat machine. However, when I login as root using Putty, the colours are not shown.

I can enable them again by typing 'su', which simply puts me back to root like I was when I logged into putty, but that isn't exaclty ideal.

Is there some configuration file or something I can use to enable shell colours when I login with Putty?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding the commands to .bash_profile, which is run at login.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the commands to .bash_profile seemed to do the trick, thanks @stark. I thought I tried that but after copying the contents of .bashrc the colours appeared on login =)